# Session not working from one php page to another

Tags: php

I was trying to design a system where i will send username from **login.php** to **upload.php** using session if login is correct.
Each time i tried , it shows an error :
**Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\interface\upload.php on line 70**
Note that i have already checked line 70 of **upload.php** , i don't think there is any error.My file uploading is alright but username is not transferred via session
It would be very helpful if you please explain whats wrong in my code. TIA.

**db.sql**

```
create database profiles;
use profiles;
create table users
(
id int(10) primary key,
pass varchar(50)
);
create table imageP
(
id int(10),
location varchar(100),
foreign key (id) references users(id)
);
insert into users values(1,'1');
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <form method="post" name="login">
        <input type="number" name="username" placeholder="Enter a Username"/>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="***"/>
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $errmsg_arr = array();
    $errflag = false;

    // configuration
    $dbhost     = "localhost";
    $dbname     = "profiles";
    $dbuser     = "root";
    $dbpass     = "";

    // database connection
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4");

    // new data
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if($user == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'You must enter your Username';
        $errflag = true;
    }
    if($password == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'You must enter your Password';
        $errflag = true;
    }

    // query
    $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id= :u AND pass= :p");
    $result->bindParam(':u', $user);
    $result->bindParam(':p', $password);
    $result->execute();
    $rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    if($rows > 0) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
        header("location: http://localhost/interface/upload.php");
    }
    else{
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Username and Password are not found';
        echo(errmsg_arr);
        sleep(3);
        header("location: http://localhost/interface/login.php");
        $errflag = true;
    }
}
?>
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>

<?php
$username = $_SESSION['username']; // holds url for last page visited.
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo 'hi '.$username;
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please try to create an [mcve] so other users can help you faster and do not need to read way to much unnecessary lines of code :)

Comment: @Hille Please suggest me which lines i should exclude.

Comment: There are two main ways for creating a minimal code (see [mcve]):  
**1. Restart from scratch.** Create a new program, adding in only what is needed to see the problem. This can be faster for vast systems where you think you already know the source of the problem. Also useful if you can't post the original code publicly for legal or ethical reasons. 
**2. Divide and conquer.** When you have a small amount of code, but the source of the problem is entirely unclear, start removing code a bit at a time until the problem disappears – then add the last part back.

Comment: ok i modified and put session_start() at beginning but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Start the session at the very top of the page and check if there is not any space before session_start(). Before any html code.

Comment: error remains same , no change.

Comment: Also remove double session_start() declaration from login.php and define username in login.php like Nel Laz advice.

Comment: ok i modified and put session_start() at beginning but still no luck , removed double session

Comment: What does die(json_encode($_SESSION)) gives you?

Comment: i tried it with echo at upload.php . it is black , shows nothing

Comment: Ok, so try to add something to it on the same page before echo. If it works then also try to add something to it from loging page (out of any conditions to be sure)

Answer (score 0):

put you `session_start();` in `login.php` at the top after `DOCTYPE`.
then try to define the `$_POST` first in `upload.php`

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
```

then you can now define `$_SESSION` as `$username`,

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
```

Comment: I think you mean BEFORE the `<!DOCTYPE html>` not after

Comment: Also the same must be done to `upload.php` and EVERY script file

Comment: i believe it is still acceptable as long as the one you want to get is/are 
 below the session_start();

Comment: But the point is that the `session_start()` must be run BEFORE ANYTHING is sent to the browser. So before any HTML is sent.

Comment: ok i modified and put session_start() at beginning but still no luck